# Unresolved reference 'cImage' in pycharm after running /usr/bin/python3 -m pip install cImage

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pycharm

**Problem explanation**

I know that `/usr/bin/python3` is my interpreter.

[image]

So I try to install the package that I want to use and it tells me that it's already installed

```
/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install cImage
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: cImage in /Users/Sam/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (2.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow>=2.9.0 in /Users/Sam/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from cImage) (7.1.2)
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 20.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 -m
```

But I also get the error that I have an unresolved reference

[image]

---

**Extra Information**

```
which pip3
/usr/bin/pip3
which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

My python3 path

```
python3 -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path))"

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload
/Users/Sam/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages
```

---

I would really like to have a single python3 and a single pip3 on my computer, instead of having to worry about all these different versions running all over the place that can't seem to install anything in the right place.

What I need solved, is that I need cImage installed to my /usr/bin/python so that I can run it in Pycharm

Comment: do you have the same problem when you try with the terminal?

Comment: @AhmetTavli Try what on the terminal?

Comment: Open the terminal, type `python` then type `from cImage import *` do you still have the same error?

Comment: @AhmetTavli Yep `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cImage'
` and I used `python3` instead of python

Comment: I would suggest create 'virtual-environment' but you want a single 'pip' and a single 'python'. Maybe creating a 'virtual-environment' and installing 'cImage' solve your problem.

Comment: @AhmetTavli I feel like virtual environments are the reason I can never install what I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/bnmnetp/cImage)

The `cImage` is imported as `import image`

```
import image

win = image.ImageWin(480, 640, "Image Processing")
original_image = image.FileImage('lcastle.gif')

width = original_image.get_width()
height = original_image.get_height()
print(width, height)
```